# usage of "fill in"

Tags: word-usage

I want to say "I can provide more details on the subject for you"
Which sounds better:

1. I can fill in more details for you
2. I can fill you in with more details on the subject

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We generally use **fill in** to mean supplying written answers to questions on a form.

Frequently, there are set spaces for such information as names, dates of birth and identity documents. In order to complete the form a person fills these in with the required information. These days this is frequently done online. The software is configured in such a way that the form cannot be submitted until all the required information has been supplied.

To **fill someone in** means to inform them - generally to give someone information about an event, often (but not necessarily) in a conversation. For example, you might fill someone in about the protocol for a coming wedding or other ceremony or about the itinerary for a company meeting.

Which phrase you would prefer would depend on the context. **Fill you in** is an informal expression. You would probably not use it in a formal situation. Prefer **give/offer you details.**

https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/fill+you+in